# How to use foreach inline databinding with observableArray of strings

Tags: knockout.js

I'm pushing strings onto an observableArray and I'd like to use the 'foreach' binding with a `<ul></ul>` element. The `<li></li>` items are just the strings.

I can't seem to see how I go about doing this. It seems the example I've seen shows the `<li>` items are referencing items inside js objects pushed onto a stack and so bind to the property of the object.

I've tried $data but that doesn't work either.

e.g.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: vm.errors()">
      <li data-bind="text: ?"></li>
</ul> 

// after json response...
$.each(response.data, function(key, errorMessage) {
     vm.errors.push(errorMessage);
});
```

Comment: Is this line still relevant `I've tried $data but that doesn't work either.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `$data` to refer to the current data at that scope level, so you can do `data-bind="text: $data"`

Comment: First time the page loads I get this though: Message: ReferenceError: $data is not defined;